# SharePoint 2010 Search Performance Level

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, crawling, index

I am currently doing SharePoint Indexing and Search Performance tuning and I came across an article from MSDN.

Link to the article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2013/11/05/changing-indexer-performance-setting-in-sharepoint-20102013/

I understand that the different performance levels relies on the resources available on the Indexing/search server. However, I am not sure if the “processors” mentioned in the article is referring to the physical or logical processor.

I have searched everywhere but could not find any answer to that. All answers which aid in my understanding are greatly appreciated.

P.S. I'm posting this from my mobile so it may not be properly formatted. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is no such documentation available which will tell you about the logical or physical.

We had an issue with search couple of years ago, after spending couple of week with Support. They called it they are looking for physical processor on the server not Logical.

So short answer for your question, it is **Physical processor**.